# d3.js Pie Chart invalid <path> attribute

Tags: d3.js, path, pie-chart

My `d3.layout.pie()` is throwing an error on my path attribute.

`Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M2.9314982754589766e-15,-47.875A47.875,47.875 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA27.875,27.875 0 1,0 1.7068514763116235e-15,-27.875Z"`

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/pggtfafy/

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
var data  = [{total_s: 22, total_l: 74, total_a: 67}];

var height      = 250
  , width       = 250
  , color       = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888"])
  , radius      = Math.min(width, height) / 2
  ;

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(radius - 10);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d){return d.key;})
    .sort(null)

var svg3 = d3.select("#sunday")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height * .5)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/8) + "," + (height/4) + ")")

var path = svg3.selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function(d){return color(d.value)});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pie needs an array of objects as data, but at the moment you've got a single-element array with one object with three properties in that single element. If you do 
`var data = d3.entries(data)` you then get an array of three objects with value and key as properties in each array entry:

```
Array[3]
0:Object
key:"total_s"
value:22

1:Object
key:"total_l"
value:74

2:Object
key:"total_a"
value:67
```

then you'd find value and key are the wrong way round so these need to be swapped in the `pie.value` and `.attr("colour"` functions (with the added qualifier for the color attribute the data needs to be accessed as `d.data.key` not `d.key` - pie sticks the initial data inside an intermediate 'data' property when you want to access it afterwards - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#_pie)

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d){return d.value;})
    .sort(null)

...

    .attr("fill", function(d){return color(d.data.key)});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pggtfafy/10/

Comment: Excellent, well explained answer. Thank you.